# How can I init this kind of Enum which contains properties and no constructor in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, enums, alamofire, init

In Alamofire, I find there is a enum:

```
public enum Result<Value, Error : ErrorType> {
case Success(Value)
case Failure(Error)
/// Returns `true` if the result is a success, `false` otherwise.
public var isSuccess: Bool { get }
/// Returns `true` if the result is a failure, `false` otherwise.
public var isFailure: Bool { get }
/// Returns the associated value if the result is a success, `nil` otherwise.
public var value: Value? { get }
/// Returns the associated error value if the result is a failure, `nil` otherwise.
public var error: Error? { get }
}
```

In struct Response, I will need to give its constructor a Result.

```
 public init(request: NSURLRequest?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, data: NSData?, result: Alamofire.Result<Value, Error>)
```

But sadly, I find there is no init inside struct Response and every property only has a getter. So how could I init a Response and use it to init struct Response?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Response(request: NSURLRequest(), response: NSHTTPURLResponse(), data: NSData(), result: Result<String,NSError>.Success("abc"))
```

or this:

```
let result: Result<String,NSError> = .Success("abc")
Response(request: NSURLRequest(), response: NSHTTPURLResponse(), data: NSData(), result: result)
```

You need to use the full `Result<…>` because Swift can only ever infer one of the generic type arguments.

Comment: Yeah! Init enum with its case of course. I was just a bit of confused because properties in enum... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this:

```
Response(request: NSURLRequest(), response: NSHTTPURLResponse(), data: NSData(), result: Result<String,NSError>.Success("lalala"))
```

Thats the easiest way.